# Pad an integer to a given length with one 0 in front and some at the end

Tags: python, sage

I need to manipulate a number as follows,

```
inputs
1
23456
6674321

outputs
01000000
02345600
06674321
```

Simply it's adding a zero to in front of number and still if less than eight characters add 0s to the end. It should be a number not a string . Is there a simple way get this done without casting from string to int or int to string?

A Sagemath code I tried is as follows. It only adds zeros to the front to pad the number to 8 characters. I need to modify this as I mentioned.

```
for num in range(1,25):
    s=randrange(2^16)
    r=mod((s-1)*503,randrange(2^32-1))
    print "%08d" % (r)
```

Comment: Your code results in a string. Are you sure you care about the type?

Comment: Please don't remove `import`s when pasting code. It takes more time for us to find what to import to run it.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz This is [Sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/) code, it does not require imports but won't run at all in plain Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pad on the right means to multiply the number by an appropriate power of 10. The power `6-floor(log(x,10))` does the job here, since you want 1000000 to not be padded.

```
for x in range(1, 101):
    print '%08d' % (x*10^(6-floor(log(x,10))))
```

This assumes that x is in a range where such padding is possible at all: that is, an integer between 1 and 9999999.

Comment: If you are using `log(..., 10)`, you can use `log10(...)`

Comment: Yes, but `log(x,10)` is preferable in Sage (it works on symbolic level until floating point evaluation is necessary) to calling Python's `math.log10` method.